# Qt UDP can't read data

Tags: c++, qt, networking, udp, qt5

I try to write a simple Multicast UDP receiver.
I can receive data when the Internet is not available, but not when it is available.
In Wireshark, Data is received in either state.

```
m_pUdpSockRecv = new QUdpSocket(this);
m_pUdpSockRecv->bind( QHostAddress("192.168.0.254") ,usPort, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress );
m_pUdpSockRecv->joinMulticastGroup( QHostAddress("239.0.0.20") );
connect(m_pUdpSockRecv, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT( fnUdpRecvData() ));
```

I think readyRead() is not called,but I can't solved this problem.
I want to be connected Internet and UDP at the same time.Because I'm getting source from Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I solved.

```
m_pUdpSockRecv = new QUdpSocket(this);
connect(m_pUdpSockRecv, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT( fnUdpRecvData() )); 
m_pUdpSockRecv->bind( QHostAddress("192.168.0.254") ,usPort, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress );
m_pUdpSockRecv->joinMulticastGroup( QHostAddress("239.0.0.20") );
```

This code is connected.
It problem is position of [connect].
[connect] should have been before [bind].